# commons-io-2.4.jar both in the libs folder and in the Android Private Libraries - is it a mistake?

Tags: android, apache-commons-io

I have the same jar file commons-io-2.4.jar both in the libs folder and in the Android Private Libraries. Is this a mistake? I got into this situation because I added the jar file to the Private Libraries and then I was told that it should be in the libs folder. I managed to put it in the libs folder, but I cannot delete it from the Private Libraries.

It looks like a method from this jar file does not work, because my application does not do anything after I call this method. And I don't get any error.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a .jar file in your libs folder should cause it to automatically show up in the Android Private Libraries section, so that should be fine. What exactly is the method's expected behavior, and what is actually occurring?

Comment: I use the following method: String s1 = FileUtils.readFileToString(file,"UTF-8"); so I want to read a file (a text file) into a string.

Comment: I wrote a Log.i message after the above method call but I don't see the Log message. And then nothing happens.

Comment: I see it does not find the file. Probably I don't give the right path to the file.

Comment: I solved the problem, I need to put the input file in the sd card and to provide the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the commons-io-2.4.jar both in the libs folder and in the Android Private Libraries because Android Private Library folder references the jars in libs folder. Private Library folder only holds references and used these during the creation of apk. And you can delete references from this Private Libraries.

According to my understanding you have to put commons-io-2.4.jar in **assests** folder and add it to **add to build path** and check **order and export** in Java Build Path. This works.

Comment: I solved the problem, I need to put the input file in the sd card and to provide the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I need to put the input file in the sd card and to provide the right path.